# can you tell someone's age from a DNA sample?

Tags: dna, telomere, forensics

So as I understand it telomeres shorten as you age. Working under that assumption..  let's say you were investigating a crime and there was some DNA evidence that had been left behind. Could you determine the age of the DNA owner by looking at the telomere length?

Comment: Not that easy. Depends on the cell type that you have. Different cell types have different telomere lengths.